# Error: ';' expected comes when executing the programm

Tags: java, file, fileutils

I have a small class that should allow me to rename and move some files and directories. Compilation gives me no syntax errors but when trying to execute, it freezes and I an error is displayed : Error: ';' expected - without specifying  a line.

My code is:

```
class Move{ 
public void Move(){}
public static void moveDir(String Name){
    try{
        File Template_1 = new File("Template_1.pdf");
        File NamePDF = new File(Name+"PDF.pdf");
        File NameFile = new File(Name);
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdir(NamePDF);
        File usr = new File(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.getUserDirectoryPath()+File.separator+"Pdf_Auswertung");
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.waitFor(Template_1,3);
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(Template_1, NamePDF);
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(NamePDF, NameFile, true); 
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(Template_1);
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveDirectoryToDirectory(NameFile, usr, true);
    } catch (IOException e){}
}
}
```

And also I coudn't figure out where a semicolon is missing or a line should be ending. 
Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I think you should probably add the whole class or - if it is too large - extract a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The error message is :"Error: ';' expected.

Comment: Now it should be minimal, comlete and Verifiable

Comment: The syntax is correct. Maybe the error is an old one. If you use an IDE, try to invalidate caches and restart the project

Comment: Change catch (IOException e){} to catch (IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); } and you may get more information about the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdir(NamePDF);
```

You are trying to create a directory using a pdf filename. You should specify where are you creating the directory.

If the NamePDF File exists you could do this to get the parent directory:

```
NamePDF.getParentFile();
```

Comment: Thanks I thought I had to create the File that way but i didn't